# Should this be "not annoying me" or "not annoy me"?

Tags: grammaticality

Which one is correct sentence? Thank you very much.

1. Can you make strong coffee, never wear perfume and **not annoying** me?
2. Can you make strong coffee, never wear perfume and **not annoy** me?

I'm watching an American drama that called Younger in Season 1 episode 1, 10:00. I heard not annoying me but subtitle was not annoy me.

Comment: I suggested some edits, one of which was removing the [tag:north-american-english] tag, since I didn't get the impression that this was actually specifically about North American. (You do mention an American TV show, but without more detail, I didn't quite see it as appropriate.) If the edit does get accepted and it's not actually what you intended in the original post, feel free to edit back.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the video/find it on youtube?

Comment: Araucaria - I couldn't find a link on youtube. but here's the link I'm watching it at 10:08 (time) , you may wait for loading and click [play button] when it shows on button. Thanks. http://www.video10d.com/gb/dramas/usdrama/2015/04/06/%E3%80%90%E7%BE%8E%E5%89%A7%E3%80%91%E5%B9%B4%E8%BD%BB%E4%B8%80%E4%BB%A3%E7%AC%AC%E4%BA%8C%E6%98%A5-%E7%AC%AC%E4%B8%80%E5%AD%A3%E7%AC%AC%E4%B8%80%E9%9B%86%E3%80%90%E5%A4%A7%E5%AE%B6%E5%AD%97%E5%B9%95-160041.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"not annoy me" is correct for two reasons:

1. We want there to be [parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)), and none of the other items use the gerund.
2. *More importantly*, we basically have a list of "Can you X", where X is each item on the list. But "can you not annoying me" is grammatically incorrect. We need to have an *uninflected* verb (i.e. the verb in the "normal" form and not in the form for the past tense or "-ing" form associated with the gerund) after "can". "not annoy" me does this; "not annoying" does not.

As pointed out by [scaramouche](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/244983/113475) in another answer, "never" might make more sense here because we use "never" in "never wear perfume", but the main problem I see is really the one I talk about in (2).

Answer (score 1):

Both options are already weird in themselves because they're not exactly very parallel, but the more correct option is "Can you make strong coffee, never wear perfume, and **not annoy** me?" because this option is not only the grammatically correct one, but it is also the one closer to having a [parallel](http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-parallelism.php) structure.

Edit: user @scaramouche's suggestions work better!

Answer (score 0):

Neither sounds right.  How about:

Can you make strong coffee, never wear perfume, and avoid annoying me?

or

Can you make strong coffee, never wear perfume, and never annoy me?

Comment: I have no idea as I'm watching an American drama that called Younger in Season 1 episode 1. I heard not annoying me but subtitle was not annoy me